# SignalR: Group broadcasts not working

Tags: c#, signalr

I think perhaps that I do not fully understand the correct way to implement groups in SignalR :)

I am using a SignalR hub coupled with some JS.
The relevant code looks as follows:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{

    public void RegisterUser()
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, username);

            //check roles
            var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, role);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        RegisterUser();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    //rejoin groups if client disconnects and then reconnects
    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        RegisterUser();
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

}
```

Stepping through this code suggests that it works as intended.

When I actually come to send a message however, broadcasting to ALL works. If I try and broadcast to a particular user through their username (their own specific group) nothing happens.

```
public void BroadcastNotification(List<string> usernames, Notification n)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        foreach (var username in usernames)
        {
            context.Clients.Group(username).broadcastMessage(new NotificationPayload()
            {
                Title = n.Title,
                Count = UnitOfWork.NotificationRepository.GetCount(),
                Notification = n.Body,
                Html = RenderPartialViewToString("_singleNotification", n)
            });
        }

    }
```

It would appear that groups do not work as I had thought. Is there a step that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your client code, but I think you have to explicitly start the hub, and "join" the "group" before you receive the "notifications". So in your client code, something like

```
$.connection.hub.start()
 .done(function() {
              chat.server.join();
 });
```

and in your hub, a "Join" method something like what you already have:

```
public Task Join()
{
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, username);
    } 
    else
    {
        // a do nothing task???? 
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // blah blah 
        });
    }   
}
```